# MyBatis Operation Gets Blocked in Spring Boot Async Method

Tags: asynchronous, spring-boot, mybatis

In my project based on Spring Boot 1.3.3, I integrated MyBatis with mybatis-spring-boot-starter 1.1.1 as persistence layer, all CRUD operation seems working fine separately, but the integration tests failed and I found the DB operation gets blocked in asynchronous task.
The test code looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SapiApplication.class)
@Transactional
public class OrderIntegrationTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldUpdateOrder() throws InterruptedException{
        Order order1 = getOrder1();
        orderService.createOrder(order1);

        Order order1updated = getOrder1Updated();
        orderService.updateOrderAsync(order1updated);

        Thread.sleep(1000l);

        log.info("find the order!");
        Order order1Db = orderService.findOrderById(order1.getOrderId());
        log.info("found the order!");
        assertEquals("closed", order1Db.getStatus());
    }
}
```

The expected execution order is createOrder() -> updateOrderAsync() -> findOrderById(), but actually the execution order is createOrder() -> updateOrderAsync() started and blocked -> findOrderById() -> updateOrderAsync() continued and ended.
Log:

```
16:23:04.261 [executor1-1] INFO  c.s.api.web.service.OrderServiceImpl - updating order: 2884384
16:23:05.255 [main] INFO  c.s.a.w.service.OrderIntegrationTest - find the order!
16:23:05.280 [main] INFO  c.s.a.w.service.OrderIntegrationTest - found the order!
16:23:05.299 [executor1-1] INFO  c.s.api.web.service.OrderServiceImpl - updated order: 2884384
```

Other related code:

```
@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {
    @Autowired
    private OrderDao orderDao;

    @Async("executor1")
    @Override
    public void updateOrderAsync(Order order){
        log.info("updating order: {}", order.getOrderId());
        orderDao.updateOrder(order);
        log.info("updated order: {}", order.getOrderId());
    }
}
```

The DAO:

```
public interface OrderDao {
    public int updateOrder(Order order);
    public int createOrder(Order order);
    public Order findOrderById(String orderId);
}
```

The Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc' 
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security' 
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web' 
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:1.1.1' 
    compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java' 
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat' 
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'  
    testCompile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-test" 
}
```

The Spring configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
@MapperScan("com.sapi.web.dao")
public class SapiApplication {

@Bean(name = "executor1")
protected Executor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    return executor;
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.primary")
public DataSource numberMasterDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = "secondary")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.secondary")
public DataSource provisioningDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name = "jdbcTpl")
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("secondary") DataSource dsItems)   {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dsItems);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SapiApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

The properties:

```
mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath*:com/sapi/web/dao/*Mapper.xml
mybatis.type-aliases-package=com.sapi.web.vo

datasource.primary.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
datasource.primary.url=jdbc:mysql://10.0.6.202:3306/sapi
datasource.primary.username=xxx
datasource.primary.password=xxx
datasource.primary.maximum-pool-size=80
datasource.primary.max-idle=10
datasource.primary.max-active=150
datasource.primary.max-wait=10000
datasource.primary.min-idle=5
datasource.primary.initial-size=5
datasource.primary.validation-query=SELECT 1
datasource.primary.test-on-borrow=false
datasource.primary.test-while-idle=true
datasource.primary.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=18800
datasource.primary.jdbc-interceptors=ConnectionState;SlowQueryReport(threshold=100)

datasource.secondary.url = jdbc:mysql://10.0.6.202:3306/xdb
datasource.secondary.username = xxx
datasource.secondary.password = xxx
datasource.secondary.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you see is caused by the fact that the whole test method `shouldUpdateOrder` is executed in one transaction. This means that any update operation that is executed in the thread that runs `shouldUpdateOrder` locks the record for the whole duration of the transaction (that is till exit from test method) and that record cannot be updated by another concurrent transaction (that is executed in async method).

To solve the issue you need to change transactions boundaries. In your case the correct way to emulate real life usage is to

1. create order in one transaction and finish the transaction
2. update order in another transaction
3. check that update is executed as expected in yet another transaction

Comment: many thanks! you saved me a lot of time, following your advice I changed the transactions boundaries and the issue solved.